# Is it possible to use dma_set_mask() to tell kernel not to use memory under 4G

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, dma, pci-e

My pcie device has a bug that it cant dma to addresses below 4G, What mask should i use with dma_set_mask to tell this to the kernel?

Comment: No you can't. DMA mask defines the area starting from address 0x00000000.

Comment: Do you refer to DMA on soc side or external device side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `pci_set_dma_mask()` does exactly the opposite of what you want: it tells the kernel not to use *higher* addresses.

The easiest thing to do will probably be to reserve the high memory at boot time and use only that memory.  Have a look at `linux/include/linux/dma-contiguous.h` for inspiration.  In particular `dma_declare_contiguous()`.

If allocating memory early isn't possible, things will get more tricky.  In that case, you'll have to read through what the 'normal' PCI allocation code does, and roll your own.

I found [the slides of this presentation](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/20140429-dma.pdf) from last year's Embedded Linux Conference insightful.  They certainly contain lots of pointers to useful headers and source code to read through. (**==> EDIT** : The link is dead and you can find the slide [here](https://elinux.org/images/4/49/20140429-dma.pdf) )

Comment: The link for the presentation is broken now. The slide can be found here : https://elinux.org/images/4/49/20140429-dma.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [DMA_API_HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) it would seem that `dma_set_mask_and_coherent(dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(64))` would be needed to enable >32bits mapping addresses. In particular (for consistent mapping):

> The consistent DMA mapping interfaces, for non-NULL dev, will by
>   default return a DMA address which is 32-bit addressable.  Even if the
>   device indicates (via DMA mask) that it may address the upper 32-bits,
>   consistent allocation will only return > 32-bit addresses for DMA if
>   the consistent DMA mask has been explicitly changed via
>   dma_set_coherent_mask().  This is true of the dma_pool interface as
>   well.

However this (dma_set_mask_and_coherent() call) is not guaranteed to work (see the HOWTO for more details). Moreover you might need to call `dma_alloc_coherent()` several times until you get a DMA address greater than 4GB...

I don't know of any way of forcing a specific mapping above 32bits.

Comment: After using dma_alloc_coherent() am i supposed to use dma_map_single()? or can my device already dma to the returned bus address?